# What does 'Can't use `!!!` at top level.' mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to create a function for creating lollipop plots using `ggplot2`. I would like to pass all argument within `...` to `aes()` within `geom_point()`. However, **I'd like to exclude the `size` argument** from passing onto `aes()` within `geom_segment()` (for obvious reasons if you look at the ouput of `a()` below). Therefore I capture `...` using `rlang::enquos()` instead of just passing it on as is. In function `a()` where I pass the `dots` to `aes()` within `ggplot()` this works without a problem. But in function `b()` I get the error `Can't use '!!!' at top level.`

I am stuck at this point and would appreciate any input to solve this issue.

```r
library(ggplot2)
data("mtcars")

d <- dplyr::count(mtcars, cyl, am)

a <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  y <- rlang::enquo(y)
  dots <- rlang::enquos(...)

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y, !!!dots)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y)) +
    geom_point()
}

b <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  y <- rlang::enquo(y)

  dots <- rlang::enquos(...)
  segment_args <- dots[names(dots) != "size"]

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y, !!!segment_args)) +
    geom_point(aes(!!!dots))
}

a(d, cyl, n, color = factor(am), size = am)
```

[image]

```r
b(d, cyl, n, color = factor(am), size = am)
#> Error: Can't use `!!!` at top level.
```

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```r
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.5/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.5.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       digest_0.6.18    withr_2.1.2     
 [4] assertthat_0.2.0 crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_0.8.3     
 [7] grid_3.5.2       R6_2.3.0         gtable_0.2.0    
[10] magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.4.2    
[13] rlang_0.4.2      lazyeval_0.2.1   rstudioapi_0.10 
[16] labeling_0.3     tools_3.5.2      glue_1.3.0      
[19] purrr_0.3.3      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_3.5.2  
[22] pkgconfig_2.0.2  colorspace_1.4-0 tidyselect_0.2.5
[25] tibble_2.1.3
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please add your `sessionInfo`.

Comment: Only two key differences between my SessionInfo and yours. I'm using R 3.6.1(shouldn't matter) and `lazyeval` 0.2.2(most probable reason) although this [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/228) suggests `lazyeval` was "abandoned" in favor of tidy eval.

Comment: I ran the code as you have it and it works just fine for me. I'm on 3.5.3

Comment: @NelsonGon Updating to version 0.2.2 of `lazyeval` did not resolve the issue. I'll try updating my `R` version.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator could you add your `sessionInfo()`. I'd like to see the differences between mine and yours.

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
stats, graphics, grDevices, utils, datasets, methods, base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.2.1

dplyr_0.8.3 R6_2.4.1 rlang_0.4.2 lazyeval_0.2.2 rstudioapi_0.10

Comment: doesn't work for me either working on R 3.6.1 and `lazyeval` 0.2.2. packages: `other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.2.0 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       digest_0.6.20    withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.1 crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_0.8.3      grid_3.6.1       R6_2.4.1         gtable_0.3.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.4.3     rlang_0.4.2      lazyeval_0.2.2  
[15] rstudioapi_0.10  labeling_0.3     tools_3.6.1      glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.2      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_3.6.1   pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_1.4-1 tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_2.1.3 `

Comment: It's not an explanation, but it appears that calling `!!!` within `ggplot()` does count as a quoting environment, whereas calling it within `geom_point()` does not

Comment: If you're actually always using the dots for `size` and `color`, why not give them as explicit arguments ? In the form `function(data, x, y, color, size)`, so that you can unquote separately with `!!`

Comment: @Romain your observation seems to be right but that surprises me quite a bit because `aes()` is a quoting function. Therefore, it shouldn't matter whether it'd be called within `ggplot()` or `geom_*()`. Having `size` and `color` as explicit argument would definitely be a solution. However, this is a special use case. While allowing users to do this I don't want to clutter the argument list with these additional args.

Comment: @NelsonGon which OS are you running R on?

Comment: @Tommy Currently on Window$ 10.

Comment: @Tommy windows 10 too `Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)`

Comment: Installing the newest version of R and tidyverse didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @Tommy in that case, for that particular lolliplot function you could override the `size` argument of `geom_segment` with a fixed value. I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue of `aes()` as you can verify [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2675). A workaround is this:

```r
b <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  y <- rlang::enquo(y)

  dots <- rlang::enquos(...)
  segment_args <- dots[names(dots) != "size"]

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y)) +
    geom_segment(aes(, y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y, !!!segment_args)) +
    geom_point(aes(, , !!!dots))
}
```

Notice the single comma in `geom_segment()` and the double comma in `geom_point()`.

Comment: I think you can mark this as the accepted answer, since it answers the problem in the most generic way !

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the instructions of rlang, you get some further details:

```
> rlang::last_error()
<error>
message: Can't use `!!!` at top level.
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
 1. global::b(d, cyl, n, color = factor(am), size = am)
 4. ggplot2::aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y, !!!segment_args)
 5. rlang::enquos(x = x, y = y, ..., .ignore_empty = "all")
 6. rlang:::endots(...)
 7. rlang:::map(...)
 8. base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
 9. rlang:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Call `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full backtrace
```

Then

```
> rlang::last_trace()
    █
 1. └─global::b(d, cyl, n, color = factor(am), size = am)
 2.   ├─ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y, !!!segment_args))
 3.   │ └─ggplot2::layer(...)
 4.   └─ggplot2::aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y, !!!segment_args)
 5.     └─rlang::enquos(x = x, y = y, ..., .ignore_empty = "all")
 6.       └─rlang:::endots(...)
 7.         └─rlang:::map(...)
 8.           └─base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
 9.             └─rlang:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

So it appears the issue is with `!!!segment_args`

EDIT 1: just playing around but since segment_args is currently a single value, I tried the following and the error indeed disappears:

```
b <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  x <- rlang::enquo(x)
  y <- rlang::enquo(y)

  dots <- rlang::enquos(...)
  print(dots)
  segment_args <- dots[[setdiff(names(dots), "size")]]
  print(names(dots))

  print(segment_args)

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y, !!segment_args)) +
    geom_point(aes(!!!dots))
}
```

This only confirms that the issue is with the usage of !!! since the above gives now an error for `aes(!!!dots)` instead and it depends on the fact that in the example there is only one element in segment_args, but it may give a handhold for further investigation

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to quote / unquote anymore. Instead, you can use the double bracket `{{ x }}` and leave the dots as dots `...`

The following works and is much easier to understand:

```r
b <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  ggplot(data, aes( {{x}} , {{y}} )) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = {{x}}, yend = {{y}}, ...)) +
    geom_point(aes(...))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Ismail. The reason I didn't leave the dots 'as is' is because I don't want to pass the `size` argument onto `geom_segment()`. What you propose does essentially what my function `a()` does but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2 :

You could override the `size` value for `geom_segment`, so that you don't have to manipulate the quoted dots before :

```
b <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  dots <- enquos(...)

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y, !!!dots)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y), size = 1) +
    geom_point(aes())
}

b(d, cyl, n)
b(d, cyl, n, color = factor(am))
b(d, cyl, n, color = factor(am), size = am)
```

---

EDIT : given my commentary about providing explicit argument, I tried this and it seems to work

```
b <- function(data, x, y, color, size) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  color <- enquo(color)
  size <- enquo(size)

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y, color = !!color)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=!!size))
}
```

---

Given your example, I'd suggest the following workaround where the needed variables are created within the function rather than being passed from `...`, so that you don't have to unquote within calls to `geom_xxx`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

data("mtcars")
d <- dplyr::count(mtcars, cyl, am)

b <- function(data, x, y, aspect) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  aspect <- enquo(aspect)

  data <- data %>% mutate(
    color = factor(!!aspect),
    size = !!aspect
  )

  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y, color = color)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = 0, xend = !!x, yend = !!y)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=size))
}

b(d, cyl, n, am)
```